# Magento 1.4 extension development

Tags: magento

HI

Magento introduced a new concept of widget in magento 1.4 , my question is whether to write a magento extension in magento 1.4 is useful or not

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento widgets are easy to use. They are the features introduced in magento 1.4 and they can be added anywhere in the pages. Widgets also provide extensive functionalities to magento.

Answer (score 4):

Magento Extensions provide a variety of different features and enhancements to a Magento System.

Magento widgets prove a way for "less-technical-users" to add a Magento Blocks to a Magento CMS page.

So yes, writing an extension in 1.4 is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a widget as another way to accomplish things in Magento. You can either make an extension or a widget. At the end of the day you will want to use the best tool for the job.

If you are looking to just add a small block of text to a page, then a widget is for you. If you need more functionality than that, an extension will probably suit you better.